# What could be the efficient way to compare multiple date column in excel and return true once there is a date change in any of the columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on excel sheet and I am trying to compare multiple date columns and return true once their is a change in any of the dates excluding blanks.

[image]

I have tried using "OR" and if statement but it's not working

I will appreciate any support

Comment: What is expected output for given data?

Answer (score 6):

A different approach, instead of checking each number, you only have to check the max and min numbers. If the max and min are equal, they must all be equal.

```
=IF(MAX(A4:D4)=MIN(A4:D4),"",TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much
this is very clear and easy to understand 

cheers

Answer (score 4):

The logical test:

```
=(COUNT(A1:D1)-COUNTIF(A1:D1,MAX(A1:D1)))>0
```

If only want to return `TRUE` and nothing if the dates are all the same, then wrap it in an `IF`:

```
=IF((COUNT(A1:D1)-COUNTIF(A1:D1,MAX(A1:D1)))>0,TRUE,"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Another way:

```
=IF((STDEV(A2:D2)>0),TRUE,"")
```

[image]

Comment: This is the first time I am coming across this "STDEV" formula 
you just solved the problem with a very simple formula.

Thank you so much
I really appreciate

Comment: @basic This is a smart solution, but I don't think it is as efficient as the OP asks. Checking for equality has less computational effort than standard deviation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative, using array version. Put on `E2` the following:

```
=LET(in,A2:D4, BYROW(in,LAMBDA(r,LET(rr,TOROW(r,1),AND(rr=MAX(rr))))))
```

A non-array version would be:

```
=LET(r,TOROW(A2:D2,1), AND(r=MAX(r)))
```

Just expand the formula down. Sometimes `LAMBDA` functions introduce some overhead, so this would be a good efficient alternative for a large dataset, but it is more difficult to maintain than using `BYROW` since it only depends on the input data `in`. Using `LET` for easier reading and composition, without it:

```
=AND(TOROW(A2:D2,1)=MAX(TOROW(A2:D2,1)))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

We use `BYROW` to iterate over each row (`r`). We need to exclude blanks (`rr`). We use for that `TOROW` with `1` as the second input argument. This function is very efficient. Now we can just compare each value to the maximum values and wrap it into an `AND` function to get the final result.

A shorter formula was already pointed out by @kevin, here is the array version:

```
=LET(in,A2:D4, BYROW(in,LAMBDA(r,MAX(r)=MIN(r))))
```

**Note**: `MIN` and `MAX` functions exclude non-numeric values, so there is no need to exclude blanks.

To minimize calculation (avoiding `MIN`, `MAX` functions), you can compare for example to the first non-blank element as follows:

```
=LET(in,A2:D4, BYROW(in,LAMBDA(r,LET(rr,TOROW(r,1),AND(rr=TAKE(rr,,1))))))
```